# Energy of an object or a system?

Tags: gravity, potential, potential-energy

We know that the gravitational potential energy of a system consisting of at least two bodies is given by $U=-\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r}$ where masses $m_1$ and $m_1$ are at a distance $r$ from each other. My question is since this energy is defined for a system, what will be the individual potential energies of them?

For example, take the example of potential energy of an object $m$ at a height $h$(which is pretty small compared to the radius of the earth)from the ground. Here we say that the potential energy of the object is $mgh$ which is derived from $\frac{mgh}{1+\frac{h}{R}}$ considering that fact that $\frac{h}{R}=0$. But this energy is actually the energy of the configuration which consists of earth and the object. Then why do we say that the potential energy of the object is $mgh$? Does that mean the potential energy of the earth is also $mgh$?

Comment: What about two objects coupled together by a spring? The potential energy is $\frac{1}{2} K (r- \ell_0)^2$. It does not make sense to ask "what is the potential energy of each body due to the spring." The spring potential energy couples the motions of the two bodies. It is wrong to think that the motions of the two bodies are independent of one another. The $mgh$ example is a special case where we can think of the motion of the object as being independent from the motion of the earth, due to the special circumstances: roughly no change in distance between the two and a very massive earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying the potential energy of the object is $mgh$ is technically incorrect, but nothing bad happens if you think of it like this, at least for simple systems.

The reason is that we can just think of the object as the system. Then the constant gravitational field is external to the system. If we want to look at changes in mechanical energy of the object moving under the force of gravity only, then we have

$$\Delta E=\Delta K=W_\text{ext}=-mg\Delta h$$

or we can just say that

$$\Delta K+mg\Delta h=0$$

This $mg\Delta h$ is usually stated as the change in potential energy of the object. But it doesn't really matter what you call it as long as you recognize the validity of the above equation.

In general you do need to be careful with it. For example, if we have two planets approaching each other, if we were to add up the (incorrect) changes in "individual potential energy", then we would be double-counting the change in potential energy.

Comment: Thank you but could you please tell me why there is nothing wrong in thinking of the object as the system?

Comment: @madness You get to decide what "the system" is. i.e. what is "internal" and "external". For example, in a collision the momentum of one object is not conserved since the force from the other object is external. But the momentum of both objects together is conserved because then the force between them is internal. The same thing happens either way; the analysis is just different.

Comment: Thanks for the clearance,i have a doubt on a slightly deviated but related topic,we know that for measuring the potential energy of an object,we are free to choose our reference level where we would assume that the potential energy of the object in that level is $0$. But let's now think rigorously in terms of a system,what do you think the other object in the system is?Is it always the earth? For example,suppose an object is $10$ meters below a ceiling. If we took the celing to be the reference level,the potential energy if that object is $mg(-10)$.

Comment: What do you think is happening here?Suppose the object is at roof level,then the potential energy of the earth and object is being taken $0$ for reference,then we say that the potential energy of the earth and object is now $mg(-10)$.Is my thinking procedure correct?

Comment: @madness I think you are correct. You can pick $U=0$ anywhere; the only thing that matters for the physics is the change in potential energy.